# VirtualHost with TCPServer

Tags: ruby, http, tcpserver

I just build my own HTTP-Webserver using the TCPServer Gem. Now I have the server running with the same (localhost) IP and port (80). But what if I have several domains on one server and want the server to be used on the localhost ip, but print different data for each domain?

Can somebody tell me how to find out from what domain the request was calling?

Comment: Why not just use Nginx or Apache? Sort of reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: You could check `Host` header of request.

Comment: Andrew: not reinventing, more like "building my own wheel" :)

Comment: How to check `Host`? @ taro - could you write a complete answer? this might help me!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you created your server with something like

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPServer.new 80
loop do
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
    ...
  end
end
```

Inside this code you may check `client.recvmsg`, which is an array. The first element of this array `client.recvmsg[0]` contains the header of the request done to your server. Something like:

```
GET /something HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4321
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,fr-CA;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2
```

As you may see, the Host header is there, in the second line. Then it is just a matter of isolating it. I did it this way:

```
def get_host(message)
  lines = message.split("\n")
  lines.shift
  host_name = ""
  lines.each{ |line|
    key_value = line.split(': ')
    host_name = key_value[1].strip if key_value[0].strip == "Host"
  }
  host_name
end
```

This will give you the Host header if you call it like

```
host_header = get_host(client.recvmsg[0])
```

inside the Thread block.